# Manual SIMD vectorialization in Fortran

Tags: fortran, sse, simd

The question is simple but I still cannot find an answer:

> How can I use SIMD Intrinsics in a Fortran code?

I don' mean to use use `!$omp` directives, and in [this example post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/explicit-vector-programming-in-fortran) from Intel. Always from the same source, I have that [Fortran does not allow SIMD calls](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/275485) at least with Intel's Fortran compiler, but that post is from 2006, quite old information.

What I mean is to *explicitly call* SIMD functions just like I do in C and C++. For instance given:

```
__m128i a;

a = _mm_lddqu_si128 ((__m128i*)(ptr)); // with ptr defined previously
```

how can one do the same in Fortran?

Be aware that I know I can write a wrapper in C and call it from Fortran, I will do this if there is no way of using just Fortran.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know of any way to do this. But may I ask why you want to explicitly call those routines and don't depend on the compiler to choose the best fitting one?

Comment: @PVitt sometimes I'd like to try different operations, and sometimes the compiler gives up on vectorizing, while I know it is possible.

Comment: That post is from 2006 and still up-to-date.

Comment: FYI, `_mm_lddqu_si128` is obsolete.  Use `_mm_loadu_si128` in new code.  (The `lddqu` instruction was faster on Pentium 4, but on everything else I think it just decodes the same as `movqdu`.)

Comment: The assembly language has sort of conceptual merged into C with the roll your own SIMD. The optimiser, OMP and !DIR (and SImD declarations) give the majority of speed. If one really has a hot spot, then Asembly is another viable option.